# Formatting USB SSD on WSL 2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, usb-device

I need to format a 1TB SSD connected through USB to the EXT4 file system. It is currently in NTFS. As I am on Windows, I thought the best way to get that is by installing the WLS 2 to be able to use Linux. This is my first time using Linux. I followed the official Microsoft guide on how to set Linux up and on how to get the USB device pop up in Linux.
I got to a point where the Windows Powershell is showing me that the drive is attached:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> usbipd list
Connected:
BUSID  VID:PID    DEVICE                                                        STATE
2-13   0781:55ae  USB Attached SCSI (UAS) Mass Storage Device                   Attached
```

And I can also see it in the WLS 2:

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0781:55ae SanDisk Corp. Extreme 55AE
```

I tried to look online for solutions to this problem but couldn't find any clear guide on how to do it. In some guides they say I should run `lsblk` to get the name of the drive, but when I run it, it seems that the SSD device is not there. I get this same list whether I run it with the SSD plugged in or unplugged from the PC:

```
~$ lsblk
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda    8:0    0 389.8M  1 disk
sdb    8:16   0     4G  0 disk [SWAP]
sdc    8:32   0     1T  0 disk /snap
                               /mnt/wslg/distro
                               /
```

I guess the 1T disk is not the usb connected SSD but the PC main storage disk, which is also 1TB.

Could anyone please help me out? I would really appreciate that, I have no idea on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bit more complex than you'd hope it would be, but you have to realize that WSL2 is really "just" a virtual machine with some integration – so, if you want to expose devices attached to your PC to WSL2, you need to do it, explicitly.

1. Find the correct path of your external disk **or** the NTFS partition on that disk. For the full path of the complete disk, you'd run

```
GET-CimInstance -query "SELECT * from Win32_DiskDrive"
```

from powershell. The path you're looking for reads something like `\\.\PHY_DISK_0`, if my memory serves me well (haven't used windows in quite some time)

2. Then, in the same powershell session, attach the volume to wsl2:

```
wsl --mount \\.\PHY_DISK_0 --bare
```

3. in the WSL2 VM, you can now see the device using `lsblk` and format it using `mkfs.ext4`